# Can I change the message in a repeating UILocalNotification?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2, uilocalnotification

I have a UILocalNotification that repeats every hour and I would like to change the message when it repeats so it is different, or rotates between 3 messages.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Also, it appears I cannot customize my repeating local notifications beyond once every minute, hour, day, etc.  What I'd like is a notification every 15 minutes.  I suspect that can't be done though... unless you know a way?

Many thanks for assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanna change the message you can acces to the `scheduledLocalNotifications` array in your app delegate and modify the message, but to do that you need the app to be running. I think it's better to simply schedule different notifications with the different messages you want to show.

About the repeating interval the simple answers is no, **you can't create your own repeating intervals**. This is one of the many limitations that `UILocalNotification`has. Many apps (included mine) had solve the problem creating a queue of notifications. I explain that topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341476/fire-local-notification-every-day-on-different-times/10343323#10343323)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, man.  Not exactly what I wanted to hear, but thanks for saving me more time and frustration in trying to find an answer. Will def check out your link now.

Comment: I hope Apple hear us an provide us more ways to personalize the notifications, because scheduling complex notifications becomes a mess with this limitations.

Comment: I think this answer should be updated, because in the meantime there are options for repeating LocalNotifications to edit the current pending / replace the current pending by identifier. 
https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_10_Local_Notification_Tutorial#Managing_Notifications