# Cordova: iOS limit for local notifications

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fire local notification every day on different times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341476/fire-local-notification-every-day-on-different-times)

I am using a [plugin](https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Phonegap-LocalNotification) to create local notifications. On android I simply create all local notifications and I am done. On iOS there is a [limit of 64](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UILocalNotification) notifications.

My question: Who can I handle this limit?

Some thoughts:

I could create some kind of buffer but I am not sure how to do that in xcode. Also I would need to periodically check if I can send you notifications from the buffer to iOS. But how could I do that if the app is not running? Could I use the notification AppDelegate handleOpenURL? How would I keep the buffer even if the app is closed?

Comment: If you use repeat interval property with NSCalendarUnit you could schedule more than 64 notifications. Reference:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: or whenever you add a notification check number of notification you have added and if it exceeds more than 64 then add the notification in sqlite table..whenever app opens or notification fires check if number of notifications count has decreased if it is so then you could get the notifications from the table and schedule a notification.use the above mentioned functionality in app delegate.  The only limitation in this approach is that user need to open the app if he dismisses the notification continously the approach is doomed.

Comment: or if you code the app using ios 6 and you want something like reminder or alarm then you could use EVENTKIT it's just a api and it provides EKStore,EKCalendar,EKEvent,EKReminder,EKAlarm using that one could easily leverage so many things with less coding.you could add events,reminders and alarms unlimitedly and you won't have to worry about the privacy..it's just for your app.Reference:http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_iOS_6_Event_Kit_to_Create_Date_and_Location_Based_Reminders