# Only first object of NSMutableArray is stored in NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, cordova, archive

I am trying to store a queue of UILocalNotification to solve the [limit problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689661/cordova-ios-limit-for-local-notifications). I used [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/537849/956397) and it does archive and unarchive my object but only the first one.

How do I archive all objects from my NSMutableArray?

#### Code

```
// init/unarchive queue
if (self.queue == nil)
{
    // try loading stored array
    NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"LocalNotificationQueue"];
    if (dataRepresentingSavedArray != nil) {
        NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
        if (oldSavedArray != nil) {
            self.queue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
        }
        else
        {
            self.queue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        self.queue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
}
// add
[self.queue addObject:notif];

// store queue
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.queue] forKey:@"LocalNotificationQueue"];
```

If I add items 1,2,3. Restart and load. I have only 3.

Add 1,2,3. Restart and load. I have 3, 1, 2.

If it matters. This is a Phonegap/Cordova CDVPlugin.

Comment: did you remember to synchronize? because it doesn't appear in the code you shared..

Comment: You mention `@synchronize(self)` in a comment: Is your code called from multiple threads concurrently?

Comment: @MartinR It is a Phonegap plugin and called from JavaScript. Maybe there is more than one thread. Not sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.queue] forKey:@"LocalNotificationQueue"];
```

You need to call

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]
```

To save the user defaults.

Comment: After I added `@synchronized(self)` around the whole function and called `synchronise` it works as wanted. Thank you and everybody!

Comment: @synchronized (self) {} makes the code inside the brackets thread-safe. Calling "synchronize" on NSUserDefaults is just saving. They might as well have called the function "save" instead of "synchronize". So the two has nothing to do with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, without the `NSKeyedArchiver`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: self.queue] forKey:@"LocalNotificationQueue"];
```

Comment: I might be blind but... how would this help?

Comment: NSUserDefaults can only store NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary, but not an array of UILocalNotification.

Comment: This does not work. But it looks like `@synchronize(self)` does help. While he still loses one of two added items sometimes...

Comment: @Daij-Djan I think the way the NSKeyedArchiver is archiving the NSArray may have something to do with the issue.

Comment: @MartinR is right, NSUserDefaults can only store those types of data, I would suggest trying an array of perhaps a JSON NSString or something you can use to recreate your UILocalNotification after reading back from it.

Comment: @OscarGomez thats what the archiver was for! it makes data, no?