# UILocalNotification: detecting alert display

Tags: ios, notifications, multitasking

I have a calendar-like iOS app which needs to raise alert everyday at specific pre-calculated times.
Is there anyway to detect if a notification alert displayed and set next schedule ( without pressing OK button and entering app)?

In other language : Is it possible to detect if "close" button of UIAlertView of UILocalNotification pressed?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can detect it thru method **- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif** of AppDelegate.

Comment: But this method is not called if "Close" button pressed.

Comment: @Radhu.: your comment is not correct. That delegate(didReceiveLocalNotification) will be called when your app gets local notification when it is in foreground.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi: You can't do this

Comment: Yes..I checked it. You are correct @AVEbrahimi. Sorry for the wrong answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't re-fire another notification based on another response. Although, you can simply create multiple notifications for all the rest of the days you wish using a `NSCalendarUnit`. The only drawback is you are limited to 64 total notifications.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341476/fire-local-notification-every-day-on-different-times/10343323#10343323) shows a trick to create a que of notifications to get passed that limit if you want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**. You **cannot do** anything with out entering into your app. There is no way to detect the **cancel** button pressed. If you cancel the notification the alert will just disappear. If you given the **action** button notification will launch the app.